# Get all matches in between two expressions

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

I have some text i would like to manipulate and substitute some lines from, but I have some problems getting all the matches I need. I only want to match lines in the second block of text. Some of the numbers can change, but the GRP 200 and GRP 300 are fixed.

Sample text:

```
SAR - GRP 200 T 0.300000 MNO 1 MRF 2 DRX 0.000000 0.000000 -1.000000 NX -1.000000 0.000000 0.000000 H1 0.15
SARB OUT
 SLNB X1 0.00000000 -6.00000000 2.00000000 X2 0.00000000 -6.00000000 2.10000000
SARB OUT
 SLNB X1 0.00000000 -6.00000000 2.10000000 X2 0.00000000 6.00000000 2.10000000
SARB OUT
 SLNB X1 0.00000000 6.00000000 2.10000000 X2 0.00000000 6.00000000 2.00000000
SARB OUT
 SLNB X1 0.00000000 6.00000000 2.00000000 X2 0.00000000 -6.00000000 2.00000000

SAR - GRP 200 T 0.300000 MNO 1 MRF 2 DRX 0.000000 0.000000 -1.000000 NX -1.000000 0.000000 0.000000 H1 0.15
SARB OUT
 SLNB X1 0.00000000 -6.00000000 0.00000000 X2 0.00000000 -6.00000000 2.00000000
SARB OUT
 SLNB X1 0.00000000 -6.00000000 2.00000000 X2 0.00000000 6.00000000 2.00000000
SARB OUT
 SLNB X1 0.00000000 6.00000000 2.00000000 X2 0.00000000 6.00000000 0.00000000
SARB OUT
 SLNB X1 0.00000000 6.00000000 0.00000000 X2 0.00000000 -6.00000000 0.00000000

SAR - GRP 300 T 0.600000 MNO 1 MRF 2 DRX 0.000000 0.000000 -1.000000 NX 0.000000 -1.000000 0.000000 H1 0.15
SARB OUT
 SLNB X1 0.00000000 3.00000000 1.80000000 X2 0.00000000 3.00000000 0.00000000
SARB OUT
 SLNB X1 0.00000000 3.00000000 0.00000000 X2 -2.45000000 3.00000000 0.00000000
SARB OUT
 SLNB X1 -2.45000000 3.00000000 0.00000000 X2 -0.30000000 3.00000000 1.80000000
SARB OUT
 SLNB X1 -0.30000000 3.00000000 1.80000000 X2 0.00000000 3.00000000 1.80000000

SAR - GRP 300 T 0.600000 MNO 1 MRF 2 DRX 0.000000 0.000000 -1.000000 NX 0.000000 1.000000 0.000000 H1 0.15
SARB OUT
 SLNB X1 0.00000000 -3.00000000 1.80000000 X2 0.00000000 -3.00000000 0.00000000
SARB OUT
 SLNB X1 0.00000000 -3.00000000 0.00000000 X2 -2.45000000 -3.00000000 0.00000000
SARB OUT
 SLNB X1 -2.45000000 -3.00000000 0.00000000 X2 -0.30000000 -3.00000000 1.80000000
SARB OUT
 SLNB X1 -0.30000000 -3.00000000 1.80000000 X2 0.00000000 -3.00000000 1.80000000

SAR - GRP 100 T 0.400000 MNO 1 MRF 2 NX 0.000000 0.000000 1.000000 H1 0.2 CB 15000 CT 15000
SARB OUT
 SLNB X1 0.00000000 -6.00000000 0.00000000 X2 0.75000000 -6.00000000 0.00000000
SARB OUT
 SLNB X1 0.75000000 -6.00000000 0.00000000 X2 0.75000000 6.00000000 0.00000000
SARB OUT
 SLNB X1 0.75000000 6.00000000 0.00000000 X2 0.00000000 6.00000000 0.00000000
SARB OUT
 SLNB X1 0.00000000 6.00000000 0.00000000 X2 0.00000000 -6.00000000 0.00000000
```

I want to match the 4 lines similar to this line in the second block:

```
SLNB X1 0.00000000 -6.00000000 0.00000000 X2 0.00000000 -6.00000000 2.00000000
```

I tried using this, but I am unable to really understand how to get all the lines from this second block:

```
(?:SAR - GRP 200.+\s+)*?(?:(?:SARB OUT)|(?<!^))*?(SLNB X1.+\s+)(?=SAR - GRP 300.+\s+)
```

https://regex101.com/r/442mwx/1

Comment: Not following the meaning of "I want to match and eventually move these lines from the second block before the original block and replace them inside the block"  I understand what first block, second block, and so on means, but what is original block?  And at the end of that statement is "inside the block" - inside what block first block, second block, original block, some other block?  Also, "I only want to match lines in the second block of text" - are you wanting to match all lines in second block? If not, then what lines beside the one you are matching?

Comment: I removed these lines since they didn’t add anything useful to the question. The main problem I have is to match all the lines starting with “SLNB X1” only in the second block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this does what you want.  A little later I may try some experiments in PowerShell to see what getting those lines look like.

I think it grabs an extra line for the last SLNB line. If that is an issue, think we can remove it.

```
(?s).+?SAR - GRP 200.+?SAR - GRP 200.+?(?:SARB OUT.+?(?<SLNB>\s+SLNB.*?))+SAR - GRP 300.*
```

Let me know how close this is and what we need to change.

**EDIT:**

Built a new RegEx from the inside out, starting with the SLNB lines, the ..? matches either newline or return+newline:

```
$RegEx = '(?s).*?SAR - .+?(?:SARB OUT..?(?<SLNB> SLNB(?: X\d(?: -?\d+\.\d+){3}){2})..?)+..?SAR - GRP 300.*'
```

Was able to test it in PowerShell, but I'm thinking there has to be simpler code:

```
foreach ($item in [Regex]::Matches($SampleText, $RegEx)[0].Groups['SLNB'].Captures) {
    Write-Host "[$($item.Value)]"
}
```

The results match only the SLNB line.

```
[ SLNB X1 0.00000000 -6.00000000 0.00000000 X2 0.00000000 -6.00000000 2.00000000]
[ SLNB X1 0.00000000 -6.00000000 2.00000000 X2 0.00000000 6.00000000 2.00000000]
[ SLNB X1 0.00000000 6.00000000 2.00000000 X2 0.00000000 6.00000000 0.00000000]
[ SLNB X1 0.00000000 6.00000000 0.00000000 X2 0.00000000 -6.00000000 0.00000000]
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me with this. Your answer is good and really helpful. In the end I used this: (?s)(?<=SAR - GRP 200.+?SAR - GRP 200.+?(?:SARB OUT.+?))(?<!SAR - GRP 300.+)SLNB.*?$(?=.+SAR - GRP 300)  which is quite clean  https://regex101.com/r/e4Y1L9/1

Comment: @Altair, thanks for sharing what you decided to use.  I see you have a positive lookahead and negative lookbehind.  That's an area of RegEx that I need to really do some work getting my head around.  I've read about, just haven't used it much.  Hope you have a lot of success in this project you are working on.